# user selected date doesnt show in the input box

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-hooks

i am using react-hook-form and Datepicker. I am trying to show the date when the user has selected one but it doesnt show. However the data still goes through onsubmit. I tried Wrapping it with Controller and putting control

[image: datepicker]

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

<Controller
  as={<DatePicker />}
  name="end"
  control={control}
  onChange={([selected]) => {
    return { value: selected };
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To show selected date you have to pass `selected` prop to the `DatePicker` component of `react-datepicker` package. Try this:

```
<DatePicker
  selected={this.state.startDate}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your selected date.

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
    const App = () => {
      const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
      return (
        <DatePicker
          selected={startDate}
          onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
          showTimeSelect
          timeFormat="HH:mm"
          timeIntervals={15}
          timeCaption="time"
          dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
        />
      );
    };
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-picker-example-1th3v)

Answer (score -1):

`react-select`'s selected property takes a moment.js date, not a plain javascript date. Try following:

```
<Controller
  as={<DatePicker />}
  name="end"
  control={control}
  onChange={([selected]) => {
    return { value: moment(selected) };
  }}
/>
```